# Fill C-Array with zeros, then copy data into it

Tags: c, memcpy, memset, strncpy

This is part of FTP client app that uses Sockets for network communication.
Before sending command to the FTP server, I want to initialize command buffer
to zeroes - no chance to mix new command with any old characters that may be
at the end of buffer (following the new command and `'\0'`.

```
//global buffers msg[1024] and cmd[16]
void sendCommand(int client_socket, char* command, size_t cmd_len) {
    int in, out;
    memset(&msg, 0, sizeof(msg));
    memset(&cmd, 0, sizeof(cmd));
    strncpy(cmd, command, cmd_len); //
    printf("Command: %s\n", cmd);   //debugging prompt
    out = send(client_socket, cmd, sizeof(cmd), 0);
    sleep(1);
    in = recv(client_socket, msg, sizeof(msg), 0);
    sleep(1);
    printf("received %d bytes: %s\n", in, msg);  //debugging prompt
}
```

Edit: Following is call of the function above:

`sendCommand(client_socket, "USER anonymous\r\n", sizeof("USER anonymous\r\n"));`

The problem is: The buffer really gets empty and then filled with the command
but server cannot recognize certain commands (e.g. PASV). The problem is in the
code because if I try to comment out `memset(&cmd, 0, sizeof(cmd));` I get expected
result for current command plus error 500 Unknown command for the tails of buffer `cmd`

Here is example answer from the server:

```
Command: USER anonymous
received 720 bytes: 331 Please specify the password.
Command: PASS dummy    
received 720 bytes: 230-FFFFF III TTTTTT  Welcome!
230 Login successful.
500 Unknown command.    //tail of old data
command: PASV    
received 94 bytes: 227 Entering Passive Mode (147,229,9,30,40,184).
500 Unknown command.    //tail of old data
500 Unknown command.    //tail of old data
command: QUIT    
received 14 bytes: 221 Goodbye.
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How is `cmd_len` computed when passed to the function?

Comment: I don't see the need for *either* of those `memset` operations. you should know *exactly* how many bytes your command is and send that, not some fixed chunk of memory with only the command at the front. I.e. I fail to see why you don't just send `command` with `cmd_len` as the chunk-size. And the receive-side shouldn't be using anything beyond that which was actually received (and you know what that was: `in`).

Comment: why don't you send `cmd_len` bytes instead of `sizeof(cmd)` ?

Comment: What if `strlen(cmd_len) >= 16`? `cmd` won't be null terminated and moreover `strncpy` will try to overrun `cmd` leading to undefined behaviour.

Comment: Writing an FTP client? Remember to support the EBCDIC transfer mode and [a gazillion of other oddities](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc114).

Comment: `strncpy(cmd, command, cmd_len);` is... less than brilliant. If the caller knows what command length is safe to copy, it can just pass a string with the correct length. If it doesn't know, why are you trusting it? `strncpy` is invented so that you pass **the size of the target buffer** to it. Not the size of the source string! The latter is pointless, to say the least.

Comment: `sizeof("USER anonymous\r\n")` > 16.

Comment: Ajay and BLUEPIXY have the answer. Buffer overrun. Lengthen cmd.

Answer (score 1):

The error was incorrect string length.
1) No `NULL` at the end of string is needed.
2) The only correct end of line is CRLF for FTP
3) Now I use `strlen` instead of `sizeof`

Answer (score 0):

are you putting the /r at the end of your command? and make sure in strncpy cmd_len will include the /r in the length